# How to configure custom properties in keycloak?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I want to use **custom properties** in the custom storage provider in **keycloak** using docker container. What is the right way to configure the new properties in user-defined or existing properties file that can be used in the custom provider java classes?
e.g:configure the hostname of external service, database type,etc